# Change classes of a dataframe like other dataframe

Tags: r, class

I have a data frame (DataFrame1) with this classes (only I print the 4th first classes):

```
> str(DataFrame1)
'data.frame':   11170 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ Var1          : int  20112 20112 20112 20121 20142 20142 20142 20122 20142 20142 ...
 $ Var2          : Factor w/ 4003 levels "1042209","1042210",..: 1 2 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 ...
 $ Var3          : Factor w/ 6 levels "2010/11","2011/12",..: 2 2 2 3 5 5 5 3 5 5 ...
 $ Var4          : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

And I create a new data frame with exactly the same columns (in the same order with the same significance).

```
> str(DataFrame2)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ Var1          : Factor w/ 5 levels "20102","20132",..: 1 3 5 5 5 4 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "b1" "b2" "b3" "b4" ...
 $ Var2          : Factor w/ 6 levels "270620","28078",..: 2 3 3 4 5 6 1
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "b1" "b2" "b3" "b4" ...
 $ Var3          : Factor w/ 4 levels "2010/11","2013/14",..: 1 3 4 4 4 3 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "b1" "b2" "b3" "b4" ...
 $ Var4          : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 1 1 1 1 2 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "b1" "b2" "b3" "b4" ...
```

I want to join this dataframes with `rbind`, but I recieve an error, because the classes are different. So, I've changed the classes:

```
class(DataFrame2[,1])<-class(DataFrame1[,1])
class(DataFrame2[,2])<-class(DataFrame1[,2])
class(DataFrame2[,3])<-class(DataFrame1[,3])
class(DataFrame2[,4])<-class(DataFrame1[,4])
```

But the classes still different:

```
> str(DataFrame2)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ Var1          : atomic  1 3 5 5 5 4 2
  ..- attr(*, "levels")= chr  "20102" "20132" "20141" "20142" ...
 $ Var2          : Factor w/ 6 levels "270620","28078",..: 2 3 3 4 5 6 1
 $ Var3          : Factor w/ 4 levels "2010/11","2013/14",..: 1 3 4 4 4 3 2
 $ Var4          : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 1 1 1 1 2 2
```

If I do `rbind` I recieve the same error.

Why in the numeric and integer classes appears *atomic*?

What can I do for the classes of DataFrame2 be the same as in DataFrame1?

Comment: Do `DataFrame2[, 1] <- as.numeric(as.character(DataFrame2[, 1]))`.

Comment: @ytk, thanks, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the first column of your second `data.frame` is a `factor`. Try converting it to an `integer` by using

```
DataFrame2$Var1 <- as.integer(as.character(DataFrame2$Var1))
```

Note that it is absolutly necessary to first convert to a `character`. This is due to the following behaviour:

```
a <- as.factor(200:205)
as.integer(a)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

However calling `as.character()` first gives the desired result:

```
as.integer(as.character(a))
[1] 200 201 202 203 204 205
```